# Backbone object defaults not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm learning about Backbone.js and I'm following a tutorial. In the tutorial a `Person` object is created with default values. But when I try to access these value with the command `var person = new Person`; and then see if the object is created with `person.get('name')` command in console I get `undefined` back. In the tutorial this should print `John Doe`. Why I'm a getting undefined back when the `Person` object has defaults?

```
// main.js
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    default: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age : 30,
        job : 'Web designer'
    },
    work : function() {
        return this.get('name') + ' is working!!';
    }
});

<head>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

If I print the person to a JSON model with `person.toJSON()` it returns an empty object. But it should not be empty because of the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

property name is `defaults`

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    defaults: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age : 30,
        job : 'Web designer'
    },
    work : function() {
        return this.get('name') + ' is working!!';
    }
});
```

[check this](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults)

Answer (score 2):

The property is `defaults`, not `default`:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend ({
    defaults: {
       // ...
    }
});
```

[Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults)

Answer (score 1):

The property you should use is `defaults` and not `default`.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 30,
        job: 'Web designer'
    }
});
```

For further info I would suggest to take a look at [What is a model?](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-model/) and obvioulsy to Backbone documentation.